# REST API with basic auth method doesn't work when trying to use inherit

Tags: rest, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

Ive got a rest api that connects with a MQ queue. Im using the IBM tools such as App connect enterprise, and MQ Explorer of IBM.

The thing its that when I send rest, using basic mode, the request results in 200 (ok). Ive assigned the values of users and passwords. But when I try to use inherit auth from parent, the answer it's unauthorized 401.

I tryed to modify the swagger doc, but it resulted very complex, and also It occurred to me that maybe if I develop an LTPA token, that could be a help.

Do you know a method to make inherit auth to work without asking the user and password again? Thank you

[image: Here i took some picks]